# Solve $3^{2x} -2 \cdot 3^{x+5} + 3^{10} = 0$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, factoring, quadratics

Here's the question: Solve for $x$ in
$$3^{2x} - 2 \cdot 3^{x+5} + 3^{10} = 0$$
I know that you have to factor something out, I'm just not sure what that something is. Thanks in advance

Comment: The whole point of the problem is that the student recognize that $3^{2x}=(3^x)^2$ and that $3^{x+5} = 3^x\cdot3^5$, reducing the problem to a simple quadratic.

Answer (score 9):

HINT:

$$\left(\dfrac{3^x}{3^5}\right)^2-2\left(\dfrac{3^x}{3^5}\right)+1=0$$

$$\iff\left(\dfrac{3^x}{3^5}-1\right)^2=0$$

Now $3^x=3^5\iff3^{x-5}=1=3^0$

As $3\ne\pm1, x-5=0$

Comment: Neat and elegant :D +1 to you, sir

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Substitute $y=3^x$ to get $$y^2-2\cdot 3^5\cdot y+3^{10}=0$$

Answer (score 5):

Use the substitution $u = 3^x$ to get $$u^2-2\cdot 3^5\cdot u+3^{10}= \left(u-3^5\right)^2 = 0$$ which is quadratic in $u$ and has a single real solution $u = 3^5$. So back-substituting yields $$3^x = 3^5 \iff x=5.$$

Comment: Better to replace $\ 243\ $ by $\,3^5\,$ throughout the answer.

Comment: Agreed, is that better?

Comment: You missed the first two, i.e. $\ 0 = u^2 - 2\cdot 3^5\, u + 3^{10} = (u - 3^5)^2\,\Rightarrow\, u = 3^5\ $ is clearer. The point is that the numerical value $(243)$ of $\,3^5\,$ plays no role in the proof. Replacing $\,3^5$ by $\,243\,$ obscures the key (power) structure that allows the proof to succeed.

Comment: @BillDubuque, Fixed; thanks! :)

Comment: Good job, +1 $\phantom{}$